# Accessing Azure documentDB using java

Tags: java, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Can anyone post some code snippet to access the Azure DocumentDB using java ?

I am able to understand how to key string to sign 
              StringToSign = VERB + "\n" + ResourceType + "\n" + ResourceId + "\n" + x-ms-date + "\n" +
                             date + “\n”;

Comment: Have you looked at the example given here (though it is in Node.js): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn783368.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Java code snippet based on JavaScript example in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn783368.aspx :

```
public static String generateAuthHeader(String verb, String resourceId,
        String resourceType, String date, String masterKeyBase64)
        throws Exception {

    // Decode the master key and setup the MAC object for signing.
    byte[] masterKeyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(masterKeyBase64.getBytes());
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HMACSHA256");
    mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(masterKeyBytes, "HMACSHA256"));

    // Build the unsigned authorization string.
    String stringToSign = verb + "\n"
            + resourceType + "\n"
            + resourceId + "\n"
            + date + "\n"
            + "\n";

    // Sign and encode the authorization string.
    String signature = Base64.encodeBase64String(mac.doFinal(stringToSign.toLowerCase().getBytes()));

    // Generate the authorization header.
    String authHeader = URLEncoder.encode("type=master&ver=1.0&sig=" + signature, "UTF-8");

    return authHeader;
}
```

I'm using the [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) for Base64 encoding/decoding.

By the way, I'm really interested in projects involving DocumentDB and Java... Please feel free to reach out to me (andrl {at} microsoft.com) if you'd like some help w/ your project!

**Edit:** A DocumentDB Java SDK has been published since this question was answered. Check out: https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-java